# C# translator from Pig Latin to English

Tags: c#, language-translation

Obviously I'm new to this, hence the content of this project. I have written some code that will translate English into [Pig Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin). Easy enough. The problem is I want to find a way to translate the Pig Latin back into English using a logic block. The clone string just seems like a cheap way to do it. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionTest
{
    public class PigLatinClass
    {

        public static void pigTalk(string sentence)
        {
            try
            {
                while (sentence != "exit")
                {
                    string firstLetter;
                    string afterFirst;
                    string pigLatinOut = "";
                    int x;
                    string vowel = "AEIOUaeiou";

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence to convert into PigLatin");

                    sentence = Console.ReadLine();

                    string[] pieces = sentence.Split();

                    foreach (string piece in pieces)
                    {
                        afterFirst = piece.Substring(1);
                        firstLetter = piece.Substring(0, 1);
                        x = vowel.IndexOf(firstLetter);

                        if (x == -1)
                        {
                            pigLatinOut = (afterFirst + firstLetter + "ay ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pigLatinOut = (firstLetter + afterFirst + "way ");
                        }

                        Console.Write(pigLatinOut);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to flip the sentence back.");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                    string clonedString = null;
                    clonedString = (String)sentence.Clone();
                    Console.WriteLine(clonedString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is there's no real rule that would work. For example: If the 3rd letter
from the last was "w" you might want to say this is a vowel word but, a consonant word starting with a "w" could also fit this rule. If the first letter was a vowel again you might want to say that this is a vowel word but, a consonant word could also fit this rule since the first letter is moved to the back (pat = atpay). The only way I think this is possible is to have an if statement that checks if w is in the 3rd position and the word starts with a vowel which would call for && operator and Visual Studio yells at you if you use it with strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Pig Latin/English translation is not a bijective function.

For example, imagine to have 2 English words like `"all"` and `"wall"`, the corresponding Pig Latin words will be always `"allway"`.

This suggest you that if you get a word like `"allway"` you can't give a unique translation in English, but (at least) two.

Comment: exactly what im thinking. so, in this particular case im not really missing something. Ive run in to a impossibility?

Comment: Yes, I think that have a unique translation is (most of the times) impossible. But perhaps you could give different translations in case of multiple possibilities...

Comment: wow what an undertaking that would take a lot of brainstorming to find all multiple cases... or I could create a function that would handle that for me. O.K. I think I'm on the right path now. Thanks digEmAll and all others that helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is homework.

What your professor probably wants is for you to convert a sentence to pig latin, and from pig latin. Keeping a copy of the original string only lets you "flip back" from sentences you already know the non-pig latin version of. It doesn't allow you to flip back from *any* string.

I think you want to structure your program like this:

```
public class PigLatinClass
{
    public static string ToPigLatin(string sentence)
    {
        // Convert a string to pig latin
    }

    public static string FromPigLatin(string sentence)
    {
        // Convert a string from pig latin (opposite logic of above)
    }

    public static string PigTalk()
    {
        string sentence;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence to convert into PigLatin");
        sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        sentence = ToPigLatin(sentence);
        Console.WriteLine(sentence);

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to flip the sentence back.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        sentence = FromPigLatin(sentence);
        Console.WriteLine(sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: no not homework just a trying to get back into coding and this seemed like a well documented project. Thanks for help! Yes building a new class to preform the logic would work great. The problem is the logic. I'm slowly thinking that its impossible. What do you think?

Comment: For a translator application, returning a copy of the original string seems like cheating...